# Toggle view on specific picker value

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to show a TextField when "custom" is chosen from the Picker.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var color: String = "red" {
        mutating willSet {
            if newValue == "custom" {
                showCutomField = true
            }
            else {
                showCutomField = false
            }
        }
    }
    @State private var customColor: String = ""
    @State private var showCutomField = false
    private var choices = ["red", "green", "blue", "custom"]
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Picker("Color", selection: $color) {
                ForEach(choices, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(.segmented)
            if showCutomField {
                TextField("Color name", text: $customColor)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Changing the value of `showCustomField` in the code does show and hide the field, however, for some reason I am not able to change the value dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showCustomField` can just be a computed property -- no need for `mutating willSet`. It should be conditional based on `color`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var color: String = "red"
    @State private var customColor: String = ""
    var showCustomField: Bool {
        color == "custom"
    }
    private var choices = ["red", "green", "blue", "custom"]
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Picker("Color", selection: $color) {
                ForEach(choices, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(.segmented)
            if showCustomField {
                TextField("Color name", text: $customColor)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code worked, thank you! But why didn't my code work?

Comment: You were making it a conditional on `customColor` instead of `color`. Then the binding would overwrite it.

Comment: I moved the `willset` block to `var color` but it's still not working.

Comment: I'm not at all sure that `willSet` will work on `@State` like that. You could use `onChange` if you really want something like that, but the above solution would be my recommendation